# Does long running tmux session affect the server and does server need shutdown?

Tags: linux, tmux

I have 2 questions that are related.

1st) I have a server running centos and is never shutdown. Does server need shutdown , if so how often and what problems can it cause if run without shutdown.

2nd) I have tmux session running on that server. It works fine. But like the server it was never exited. Is it necessary to close the tmux session on some interval ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are regularly updating your CentOS system then you will occasionally need to restart it to load a new kernel which will contain patches and security updates.

If you're not regularly updating your system then you should be.

Regarding tmux, if you're not experiencing problems related to or caused by it then there should be no reason to restart it.

Comment: Well, you might need to restart if you apply an update (that doesn't require a reboot) that changes a file/library related to tmux, or whatever applications are withing your tmux session.

Comment: @Zoredache: Good point well made.